# Galaxy S firmware before Value Pack

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Can someone tell me which was the previous version of Galaxy S firmware before the current/latest Value Pack (XXJV4)? I am considering to downgrade, but I am not sure about version/code of that. Thanks!

Comment: What region?  It should be something like XXJV3 or XXJU# (etc.)

Comment: I am in the UK.

Comment: Which phone network are you on and did they supply your phone? It also makes a difference whether your phone had any branding/customization/tweaking by your phone network, eg Vodafone tweak the firmware and have a *VOD* code in the firmware version.

Comment: Unlocked, no branding.